# How to create a footnote-tooltip in html files generated from Pandoc

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make the hover-over tooltip in files generated from pandoc.
Pandoc convert a markdown file to an HTML like this :

```
# Test

Test^[this is a first footnote.].

TestTest^[this is a second footnote.].
```

to

html

```
<p>Test<a href="#fn1" class="footnote-ref" id="fnref1"><sup>1</sup></a>.</p>
<p>TestTest<a href="#fn2" class="footnote-ref" id="fnref2"><sup>2</sup></a>.</p>
<section class="footnotes">
    <hr />
    <ol>
        <li id="fn1">
            <p>this is a first footnote.<a href="#fnref1" class="footnote-back">↩</a></p>
        </li>
        <li id="fn2">
            <p>this is a second footnote.<a href="#fnref2" class="footnote-back">↩</a></p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Then, I tried to write a css code for the tooltips, but nothing works :

```
.footnote-ref {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.footnote-ref .footnotes ol li {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    /*width: auto;*/
}
.footnote-ref .footnotes ol li::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
}
.footnote-ref:hover .footnotes ol li {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I know a css code is wrong because I only followed some examples of css. Since Pandoc automatically convert Markdown to HTML, I can't modify the tags. I'm guessing I should use jquery by adding header.html.

It would be very nice if I can make reference tooltips like on this site (See "2.3 Citations" section) :
https://thomaspark.co/project/pubcss/demo/acm-sig-sample-web-theme.html

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybzJj.png)

Comment: *"I can't modify the tags"*. You can use Lua filters in Pandoc.